# Using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem to prove equality of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm looking for a proof using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem of the following:

Prove that in $C^1[0,1]$ vector-space,
$\left\|f\right\|=\left|f(0)\right|+\left\|f'\right\|_\infty$ norm is equivalent with $\left\|f\right\|_\infty+\left\|f'\right\|_\infty$.

I'm trying to use the following inequality:

$$
\alpha(\left\|f\right\|_\infty + \left\|f'\right\|_\infty) \leq \left|f(0)\right|+\left\|f'\right\|_\infty \leq \beta(\left\|f\right\|_\infty + \left\|f'\right\|_\infty); \beta = 1
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in[0,1]$, 
$$|f(x)-f(0)|\leq x\sup_{y\in[0,x]}|f'(y)|\leq x\|f'\|_\infty$$
by Lagrange's theorem.
Hence
$$|f(x)|\leq|f(0)|+x\|f'\|_\infty\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty$$
so, taking the supremum as $x$ varies in $[0,1]$, you get
$$\|f\|_\infty\leq |f(0)|+\|f'\|_\infty$$
so
$$\|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty\leq |f(0)|+2\|f'\|_\infty\leq 2|f(0)|+2\|f'\|_\infty$$
hence $\alpha=1/2$ works.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $ |f(t)| = |f(0)+\int_{0}^{t}f'(x)dx| \le |f(0)|+\int_{0}^{t}|f'(x)|dx \le |f(0)|+\|f'\|_{\infty}$ for $0 \le t \le 1$.